# How can I call another android application in my android application's user interface?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

I working on a android application which acts like a menu. There is 2 button on it and One of them have to call navigation application (google navigation,sygic or tomtom) but it must be in my application, it must not open another activity or page. Is it possible ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible ?

Not generally. It is theoretically possible that "sygic or tomtom" have some sort of API for this, but since sharing a UI between processes is rather difficult in Android, I will be surprised if those firms created such an API.

You are welcome to find some firm with an SDK for navigation and integrate that with your application. Note that most likely there will be substantial licensing fees.

You are also welcome to investigate Web-based navigation solutions, embedding them via a `WebView`. Once again, I would expect there to be licensing fees.

Comment: First af all thank you, I am working on an app like Android Auto. For now, my application call google navigations with new page and then returning to my application is problematic. Is this licesing precedures also affect me? Because in Android Auto concept, you can freely use your licensed/installed application on your phone.

Comment: @HamzaGÜPÜR: "Is this licesing precedures also affect me?" -- please discuss this with qualified legal counsel.